# how to remove a ubuntu package from manual install list without actually remove it?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

whenever you install a package in ubuntu, it is added to manual install and the system will make sure it is updated and configured correctly. but i cannot find a way to remove the packages from the manual install list.

i want to do this so i let the package system to take care of that package and remove it when it is unnecessary to my system.

thanks,
David

Comment: I see you've got a good answer, but for future reference this sort of question is better asked over on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as with most debian based package questions, is Aptitude.

```
sudo aptitude 
/(package name here)
hit n until you find the correct package.
M marks it as auto.
m marks it as manual.
those options are also in the "Package" menue.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo aptitude markauto PACKAGE_NAME
```